# Capacitor bursting

Tags: capacitor, voltage-regulator, burst

I attached a 0.1 uF capacitor at the input of a 5 V voltage regulator. It was rated 50 V and my input was 37 V.

After some time the capacitor burned out. I tried the same with another capacitor but it did the same. What could be the reason and how to solve it?

Comment: Please provide a data sheet link for the capacitor.

Comment: Buy name brand capacitors from reputable sellers. Ali, Amazon and ebay isn't one.

Comment: What's the type of capacitor? Ceramic, tantalum electrolitic etc? If it's polarised and fitted backwards that would also be a cause of it failing. Either that or you have a bunch of fake capacitors.

Comment: Maybe you broke the capacitors by attaching it incorrectly? Heating too much while soldering, bending leads too forcibly or applying too much pressure to capacitor can degrade a capacitor. How did you attach it?

Comment: Was the input DC or did it have some ripple?

Comment: Its input was DC and it was given to an electrolytic capacitor

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You got fake capacitors most likely. The 50V rating on them is imaginary. Unfortunately, that's all too common. I got a whole "noname" capacitor kit, nicely packaged, that was supposed to be 50V rated. The capacitors look like they have a 16V rating and start failing a bit above 20V :( It's still useful, just not at 50V.